# Problem understanding C++ string - why are we using strcpy here?

Tags: c++, string

```
string str;
str="hi brother";
char * cstr = new char [str.length()+1];
strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());
```

why don't we just do this

```
char *cstr = str.c_str();
```

if I try to do this then it gives an error. I can't understand what's the meaning of const char and char

why do we use strcpy function here?

Comment: Think about the difference if you wrote `cstr[0] = 'x';` as the next line.

Comment: We don't do this because it gives errors, as you found out. The meaning of `const` as qualifier is explained in any C++ tutorial, please continue with that to learn its implications.

Comment: besides the error, the difference here is that `cstr` is a self-owning object after using `new`. when you assign it to the `c_str()` instead, it only points to that string data, so any modification happens to both `str` and `cstr`

Comment: Probably because whoever wrote that code does not understand C++ very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constant char pointer instead (if you want a read-only version):

```
const char * cstr = str.c_str();
```

or copy it to a `char[]` using `strcpy()` if you want to modify the new string (`char[]`) later

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strcpy` there if you want `cstr` to end up pointing to a copy of the string, or really character array. If you want it to end up pointing to the same character array that `str` holds internally then you would use

```
const char* cstr = str.c_str();
```

it must be `const` because `str` owns that string so only it is allowed to modify it; this is what `const` means.

Comment: With C++17 you can also use `str.data()` to get a non-const pointer, which may be a better comparison to the `strcpy` implementation.